# How do I use Hasura/postgres uuid with apollo-ios and swift

Tags: swift, hasura, apollo-ios

I have a table defined in Hasura (Postgres) using native `uuid` as the field datatype.  My goal is to create an update mutation from Swift but the uuid type is not mapped implicitly from Postgres through Hasura and Apollo to Swift.  The Hasura documentation states that the uuid type supports using `String` but when I define the variables, in the update mutation, as a `String!`,

```
mutation RedeemMagicLinkCode($code: String!, $iosIdentifierForVendor: String!) {
  __typename
  update_entityname(where: {code: {_eq: $code}, iosIdentifierForVendor: {_is_null: true}}, _set: {iosIdentifierForVendor: $iosIdentifierForVendor}) {
    returning {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error from the Apollo code gen build step that `Variable "$code" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "uuid".`. When I change that to `uuid!`,

```
mutation RedeemMagicLinkCode($code: uuid!, $iosIdentifierForVendor: uuid!) {
  __typename
  update_en...
```

The code gen step completes, producing API.swift, but several instances of the compile error `Use of undeclared type 'uuid'` raise and are now coming from a failure during compile of the Apollo generated API.swift.

```
/// API.swift
...
public let operationName = "RedeemMagicLinkCode"

  public var code: uuid
  public var iosIdentifierForVendor: uuid
...
```

Can someone point me in the right direction for letting Swift know what a uuid is or defining my query so that I can pass a String as a parameter through the Apollo managed mutation?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

OM(Goodness), I might need to blush at how simple this solution was.

I considered the error `Use of undeclared type 'uuid'` plus the documentation that Hasura will accept a `String` for this custom scalar...

```
/// API+typealias.swift
public typealias uuid = String
```

I placed the above type alias code in a file all by itself in the folder where my GraphQL files are and voila, it worked great!

I'm not thrilled with this public type alias now hanging out at the global scope but I am thrilled with a working data service